# で in a structure

Tags: particle-で

Today, I read one grammar and it explained "前件で結果、後件で理由を言う"

I'm not sure what で functions here. In my opinion I translate 前件で結果 into "Summarize by the previous thing" I think する is omitted from 結果 （結果する）

And this "、" I don't know what this means. Is this same as "and" in English ?

Answer (score 3):

That particle's function is to specify location. And yes - that comma means "and' or like juxtaposition.
So the step-by-step translation is like:

前件で結果、後件で理由を言う

→ in the former: 結果; in the latter: 理由 を言う

→ the result in the former; the reason in the latter, it says.

→ It says the result in the former, then the reason in the latter.

Thanks for learning Japanese!

Comment: That particle's function is to specify location. Why use で here ? Why does not specifying location  use に instead ?

Comment: The particle に has the meaning near to 'at' or 'to'. So in this sentence, it is not proper.

Comment: But an exception case is 〜にある, which means 'in'.